# Chained promise resolving to undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

These are my functions (simplified):

```
fetchSth: (url) => {return fetch(url)}

parseSth: (res, bot, editMsg) => res.text().then( res => {
  return Promise.resolve(['aa', 'bb']);
})
```

This is my chain:

```
reqs.fetchSth(url)
  .catch(reqs.errInFetch)
  .then((res) => reqs.parseSth(res, bot, editMsg)
    .then(msg => console.dir(msg)) //prints undefined
    )
      .then(msg => {
         console.dir(msg); //prints undefined
      });
```

Why does it resolve to undefined?

Comment: Note: return ["aa","bb"] is enough...

Comment: Please post the actual functions. Your simplified one does work.

Comment: oh sorry. there was an error in my actual function. the promise was never returned. fixed it

Answer (score 0):

What is returned from `reqs.errInFetch`? If it's not throwing another error or returning a rejected promise, the chain will continue to resolve to the next `then` using whatever `reqs.errInFetch` returned.  That's the first place I'd look.  If that's the problem you have to decide how you want to handle a fetch error.  If it's something your chain can recover from, include that logic in `reqs.errInFetch`.  Otherwise throw an error or return a rejected promise you can catch at the end of the chain.

Comment: oh sorry. there was an error in my actual function. the promise was never returned. fixed it